# How to remove excerpts in joomla articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, templates

On my homepage, I am listing all my blog posts from a category. I don't want to show there any excerpt of articles neither full article instead of a title and featured image. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you have made an attempt to self-solve, please provide that.  If you did some research before posting, please show us so that we don't suggest something that you have already seen.  Editing your question to include these important details will make your question more attractive to answer.

Comment: It seems that the volunteers wishing to help are not completely sure of your requirements.  Please use different wording to describe what you desire.  Alternatively, you might show a screenshot and use an image editor to indicate what you do and do not want.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you want to just show the title of the articles in your blog and not the Introduction Text or the Full text of the Article.

If you want the article list to appear in the body of your Homepage then you need to update the Menu Item Type for the Home page and select Articles->Category List.

If you want to display a list of the articles off to the side of your home page then look at the various Modules available under the Extension menu for listing Articles. i.e. Most Recent.

https://docs.joomla.org/Help39:Menus_Menu_Item_Article_Category_List

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're after, but what I *think* you're asking for is how to make the category blog that you have designated as your home page show a list of article titles, no intro text.

To do that, go to the "Blog Layout" tab of the menu itemand put zeroes in the boxes for Leading Articles and Intro Articles, then put in a number for how many link articles you want in your list. Then you'll want to adjust the values on the "Options" tab until you see what you want.

If that's not what you're after, please expand your original question to give us more specifics so we can figure out what you're trying to do.

If nothing else works, a template override can certainly get you what you're after.